# Multiple search criteria within Excel Formula

Tags: excel-formula

I have a sheet with the following demo data (yeah the content is german don't mind that)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/egOXI.png]

And I need a formula which will search for the criteria in `A1` and `B1` and returns the respective value out of the matrix `E3:M8`

For example

Search criteria is: **X** and **2** - Return value should be **wert2**

or

Search criteria is: **Z** and **1** - Return value should be **wert7**

I think I can somehow use an `INDEX` formula but not quite sure how to do so..

Hope you can help

Comment: are the field header values X Y and Z or is that just for the purpose of sample data? Reason I ask is was thinking of doing something with the ASC code to determine the column.

Comment: No, thats just sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if your data has merged cells. If you want to keep life simple, avoid merged cells.

Your data has the same 1,2,3 sequence in each section x, y and z. I assume that these values will always be the same. With the data laid out like in your screenshot, the formula you need is

```
=INDEX($E$3:$M$7,MATCH(B1,$E$3:$E$7,0),MATCH(A1,$E$3:$M$3,0)+2)
```

[image]

Because of the merged cells it is impossible to select the range in column E for the first Match function. It needs to by typed instead. You also need to adjust the second Match result for the column, since the x, y, and z are stored in the first of the merged three cells, but you want the value underneath the third of the merged cells. Avoid merged cells.

A better data layout would be this:

[image]

The Index/Match could be simplified to

```
=INDEX($E$3:$H$7,MATCH(B1,$E$3:$E$7,0),MATCH(A1,$E$3:$H$3,0))
```

Or you could use Vlookup

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,$E$3:$H$7,MATCH(A1,$E$3:$H$3,0),FALSE)
```